# Select first child from unordered, prioritized list

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

## Background

Third-party software libraries sometimes include a set of licenses developers may choose when using the library. Some licenses can be detected using [ORT](https://github.com/oss-review-toolkit/ort/) to produce an [SPDX identifier](https://spdx.org/licenses/). We'd like to eliminate the manual process of selecting particular licenses each time, deferring instead to a predefined, prioritized list.

Not all licenses are included in the list.

## Code

This section defines the source files.

### priorities.xml

The order of entries determines the license to choose when a selection is available:

```xml
<priorities>
  <license>Apache-2.0</license>
  <license>MIT</license>
  <license>BSD-2-Clause</license>
  <license>BSD-3-Clause</license>
  <license>CDDL-1.0</license>
  <license>EPL-2.0</license>
  <license>MPL-2.0</license>
  <license>LGPL-3.0</license>
</priorities>
```

This document is loaded using:

```xml
  <xsl:variable
    name="PRIORITY"
    select="document( resolve-uri( 'priorities.xml', base-uri( / ) ) )" />
```

### libraries.xml

These simplified license entries form the input document:

```xml
<copyrights>
  <copyright>
     <title>Grizzly HTTP framework</title>
     <licenses>
        <license>CDDL-1.0</license>
        <license>GPL-2.0-or-later</license>
     </licenses>
  </copyright>
  <copyright>
     <title>Java™ JSON Tools Jackson Coreutils</title>
     <licenses>
        <license>LGPL-3.0-or-later</license>
        <license>Apache-2.0</license>
     </licenses>
  </copyright>
  <copyright>
     <title>Javassist</title>
     <licenses>
        <license>LGPL-2.1-only</license>
        <license>MPL-1.1</license>
        <license>Apache-2.0</license>
     </licenses>
  </copyright>
  <copyright>
     <title>Linux Kernel</title>
     <licenses>
      <license with="Linux-syscall-note" order="before">GPL-2.0-only</license>
     </licenses>
  </copyright>
  <copyright>
    <title>Eclipse Temurin™</title>
    <licenses>
      <license with="Classpath-exception-2.0">GPL-2.0-only</license>
    </licenses>
  </copyright>
</copyrights>
```

## Output

The desired output reduces the licenses to a single entry:

```xml
<copyrights>
  <copyright>
     <title>Grizzly HTTP framework</title>
     <licenses>
        <license>CDDL-1.0</license>
     </licenses>
  </copyright>
  <copyright>
     <title>Java™ JSON Tools Jackson Coreutils</title>
     <licenses>
        <license>Apache-2.0</license>
     </licenses>
  </copyright>
  <copyright>
     <title>Javassist</title>
     <licenses>
        <license>Apache-2.0</license>
     </licenses>
  </copyright>
  <copyright>
     <title>Linux Kernel</title>
     <licenses>
      <license with="Linux-syscall-note" order="before">GPL-2.0-only</license>
     </licenses>
  </copyright>
  <copyright>
    <title>Eclipse Temurin™</title>
    <licenses>
      <license with="Classpath-exception-2.0">GPL-2.0-only</license>
    </licenses>
  </copyright>
</copyrights>
```

## Problem

Conceptually, I'd like to filter out the licenses based on the position of each input license in the priorities list, then select the first. As a series of transforms the relevant section of the input document might start as:

```
 <licenses>
    <license>LGPL-2.1-only</license>
    <license>MPL-1.1</license>
    <license>Apache-2.0</license>
 </licenses>
```

Then we could assign the priority based on the position in the priorities list:

```
 <licenses>
    <license priority="INFINITY">LGPL-2.1-only</license>
    <license priority="7">MPL-1.1</license>
    <license priority="1">Apache-2.0</license>
 </licenses>
```

Then sort based on priority:

```
 <licenses>
    <license priority="1">Apache-2.0</license>
    <license priority="7">MPL-1.1</license>
    <license priority="INFINITY">LGPL-2.1-only</license>
 </licenses>
```

Then select the first child:

```
 <licenses>
    <license priority="1">Apache-2.0</license>
 </licenses>
```

I believe this "algorithm" would ensure that any license that doesn't have a corresponding priority would be selected by default.

## Constraints

These constraints will have been met before the transformation step occurs:

- It is an error to have multiple licenses present in the input document without at least one match in the license priorities listing. I don't think we can realistically select the first license in such cases.
- It is an error for each entry in the input document to not have a license (i.e., we can enforce this using schema validation).

## Question

What would be an expedient way to filter the licenses using XSLT 3.0?

Comment: Have a look at the `index-of()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```xml
<xsl:template match="copyright/licenses">
  <licenses>
    <xsl:copy-of 
       select="$PRIORITY//license[. = current()/license][1]"/>
  </licenses>
</xsl:template>
```

This takes advantage of the ability to do a one-to-many comparison using `=`.

---

Not all the licenses in the source document are listed in the priorities file, so to include the default value and retain the attributes from the source document, try:

```xml
<xsl:template match="copyright/licenses">
  <licenses>
    <xsl:copy-of
      select="(license[.=$PRIORITY//license[. = current()/license][1]], license)[1]" />
  </licenses>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion.

To simplify my test I defined the `PRIORITY` variable inline instead of using `document()` but of course you can stick with your approach of reading it from an external file.

An explanation:

The template matching `licenses` copies only one of the `license` child elements.

First it uses the XPath 3 `sort` function to sort the licenses. The last parameter to that function is a function which maps an item to a sort key; the supplied function looks up the item (i.e. the license name) in the sequence of `PRIORITY` licences, and returns the resulting position, or if it's not found in the map, it returns infinity.

Then the first (highest priority) license from that sorted sequence is copied.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="3.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map">

  <xsl:variable name="PRIORITY">
    <priorities>
      <license>Apache-2.0</license>
      <license>MIT</license>
      <license>BSD-2-Clause</license>
      <license>BSD-3-Clause</license>
      <license>CDDL-1.0</license>
      <license>EPL-2.0</license>
      <license>MPL-2.0</license>
      <license>LGPL-3.0</license>
    </priorities>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="licenses" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="
        sort(
          license,
          (),
          function($license) {
            (index-of($PRIORITY//license, $license), xs:double('INF'))[1]
          }
        )[1]
      "/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's closer to how I imagined I would approach this - except that I would use a *key* so that only related licenses from priorities.xml would be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of Michael Kay's suggestion using keys - which I believe would be more efficient.

For better readability, I have used variables. If you prefer concise code, you can replace each variable reference with its `select` expression.

```
<xsl:key name="lic" match="license" use="." />

<xsl:template match="licenses">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="related" select="key('lic', license, $PRIORITY)" />
        <xsl:variable name="top" select="key('lic', $related[1], current())" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="($top, license)[1]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a solution using keys**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="kLicenseByVal" match="license" use="."/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="vPriorities">
    <priorities>
      <license>Apache-2.0</license>
      <license>MIT</license>
      <license>BSD-2-Clause</license>
      <license>BSD-3-Clause</license>
      <license>CDDL-1.0</license>
      <license>EPL-2.0</license>
      <license>MPL-2.0</license>
      <license>LGPL-3.0</license>
    </priorities>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="licenses">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="((* ! key('kLicenseByVal', ., $vPriorities))[1], *[1])[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<copyrights>
  <copyright>
    <title>Grizzly HTTP framework</title>
    <licenses>
      <license>CDDL-1.0</license>
      <license>GPL-2.0-or-later</license>
    </licenses>
  </copyright>
  <copyright>
    <title>Java™ JSON Tools Jackson Coreutils</title>
    <licenses>
      <license>LGPL-3.0-or-later</license>
      <license>Apache-2.0</license>
    </licenses>
  </copyright>
  <copyright>
    <title>Javassist</title>
    <licenses>
      <license>LGPL-2.1-only</license>
      <license>MPL-1.1</license>
      <license>Apache-2.0</license>
    </licenses>
  </copyright>
  <copyright>
    <title>Linux Kernel</title>
    <licenses>
      <license with="Linux-syscall-note" order="before">GPL-2.0-only</license>
    </licenses>
  </copyright>
  <copyright>
    <title>Eclipse Temurin™</title>
    <licenses>
      <license with="Classpath-exception-2.0">GPL-2.0-only</license>
    </licenses>
  </copyright>
</copyrights>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<copyrights>
   <copyright>
      <title>Grizzly HTTP framework</title>
      <licenses>
         <license>CDDL-1.0</license>
      </licenses>
   </copyright>
   <copyright>
      <title>Java™ JSON Tools Jackson Coreutils</title>
      <licenses>
         <license>Apache-2.0</license>
      </licenses>
   </copyright>
   <copyright>
      <title>Javassist</title>
      <licenses>
         <license>Apache-2.0</license>
      </licenses>
   </copyright>
   <copyright>
      <title>Linux Kernel</title>
      <licenses>
         <license with="Linux-syscall-note" order="before">GPL-2.0-only</license>
      </licenses>
   </copyright>
   <copyright>
      <title>Eclipse Temurin™</title>
      <licenses>
         <license with="Classpath-exception-2.0">GPL-2.0-only</license>
      </licenses>
   </copyright>
</copyrights>
```